# Opening Runnable .jar File with arguments in other Java program

Tags: java

I wrote a game in JavaFX and I need to run it with my VM Arguments:

--module-path "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media

I had to add javafx.media because I use sounds in my game.
I can't run it with double click on exported Runnable JAR File. Also I wrote another program with GUI which opens my game by opening Runnable JAR File but it can't open. Here is how I open this JAR file :

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","start", "C:\\Users\\Kamil\\Desktop\\aaaaa\\v0.1\\WAT_Invaders.jar");
    Process proc2 = pb.start();
    proc2.waitFor();
```

The same game without sound can start. Also, when I want to export my game, Eclipse says:
"VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR. Arguments can be passed on the command line when launching the JAR"

Any idea how to open it with correct arguments?

Here is how I added sound:
declaration

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
private Media me;
String shoot_path = new File("src/shot.wav").getAbsolutePath();
```

using sound

```
    me = new Media(new File(shoot_path).toURI().toString());
    mp = new MediaPlayer(me);
    mp.play();
```

Comment: add `System.out.println(new String(proc2.getErrorStream().readAllBytes()))` after `proc2.waitFor()` and check whether you get any expception or not.

Comment: This is what I got on console
Space Invaders are about to start!
Space Invaders are running!

Space Invaders are about to start!
Space Invaders are running!

Because I have these lines
System.out.println("Space Invaders are about to start!");         
System.out.println("Space Invaders are running!");